# Why is [,] a valid array literal in javascript?

Tags: javascript, grammar

For some reason `[,]` is a valid array literal in javascript. It is a 1-element array. `[,,]` works as well, and so on. I am looking at the grammar to see why this parses, but as far as I can tell an empty expression shouldn't be allowed there.

Any ideas?

Comment: [It's the same as asking why `[]` works.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Extra_commas_in_array_literals)

Comment: Why wouldn't an empty expression work ? Seems like it should to me

Comment: My guess it that `[,] === [undefined, undefined]`.

Comment: Why does it work? Ask the spec makers.

Comment: @Johan - Nope, `[,,,,,] === []`... ignored

Comment: if `[,] === [undefined,undefined]` then the length of the array should be 2. But it's not. It's 1

Comment: Why are you guys comparing arrays with `===`

Comment: @adeneo Right. Ignored?

Comment: Derek: [] works because it's explicitly defined in the grammar: http://www-archive.mozilla.org/js/language/grammar14.html#N-ArrayLiteral whereas ElementList and LiteralElement don't seem to allow empty expressions.

Comment: @Johan - `[,]` would be the same as `[undefined]` since the last comma with empty item is ignored.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 - It's just pseudo code to show what we think it equals.

Comment: `[,,,undefined,,] === [3: undefined]` that's somewhat strange ?

Comment: @adeneo - What I got is `[undefined × 3, undefined, undefined × 1]` which seems correct to me.

Comment: Which grammar are you looking at? You should be looking into the [ECMAScript Language Specification, 5.1 Edition (HTML version)](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/)

Comment: yeah I might be looking at the wrong one...

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 - Chrome just spit out `[3: undefined]` in the console, seemed like a strange result, but I guess that's chrome's way of showing it ?

Comment: @WilliamCasarin Yes, you might. Unfortunately, it does not make sense to continue here until *you tell us which one* and *the environments in which you tested, exactly*. Because [there is no “javascript” (programming language)](http://PointedEars.de/es-matrix).

Comment: @adeneo - I'm not sure what version of Chrome you are using but on mine it shows something different than yours: http://i.stack.imgur.com/RJlBV.png

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 - Mine actually shows the same, I was doing this -> http://jsfiddle.net/xWgpS/

Comment: @PointedEars thanks that was it. Googling javascript grammar gives you an older spec as the first result :(

Comment: @adeneo - 3 `undefined` with a length of 5, that probably means there are 5 `undefined item in the array.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 No, just the `length` property is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems I was looking at an older language spec. The [ECMAScript Language Specification, 5.1 Edition (HTML version)](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/)

Defines an ArrayLiteral as:

```
ArrayLiteral :
    [ Elision opt ]
    [ ElementList ]
    [ ElementList , Elisionopt ]

Elision :
    ,
    Elision ,
```

The Elision rule seems to define this case

It [allows](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Extra_commas_in_array_literals) for array element "placeholders" in some sense.

I ran into this issue when dealing with leading commas:

```
var x = [
  , something
  , somethingElse
  , 2
]
```

I was wondering why I was getting an `undefined` for the first element.

Thanks PointedEars and Derek 朕會功夫

Comment: Or in the [official PDF specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf), page 63, bottom.

Comment: You must be mistaken. The `Array` initialiser was introduced with ECMAScript Edition 3, and the productions `ArrayLiteral : [ Elision_opt ]` and `Elision : ,` are on page 40 of the [December 1999 revision](http://ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf).

Comment: To be clear, an elision doesn't create a member with a value of *undefined*, it just increases the length, there is no member. `var a = ['a',,'b']` creates an array with length 3 and no member at position 1, i.e. `'1' in a` returns false. And IE has (had?) an issue with trailing elisions, it increases the length by one too many: `[,].length` should be 1, but IE says 2.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, this is a very good question.
I have never noticed it before.

I have made a fiddle that further 'exploits' this phenomena:
http://jsfiddle.net/xJnrK/

I think it has something to do with the way javascript handles undefined variables.
Javascript uses either 'null' or 'undefined' for empty variables. My guess it is just to prevent code to crash unlike Java where you must give all variables you call a value.

It gets more crazy, undefined is not a reserved word. You can actually override it (in a local scope) using:

```
function replicateMozilla()
{
    var undefined = '2';

    console.log(undefined);
}

replicateMozilla();
```

More about undefined:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined